# Show Rails errors, notices and devise messages in one place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, erb

I have my application.html.erb file where this code located:

```
<% if notice %>
 <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% elsif alert %>
 <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
<% end %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
```

All is great, but form validations are made by using (as usual), this:

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
    <% if @project.errors.any? %>
        <h2><%= pluralize(@project.errors.count, "error") %> prevented this project from saving:</h2>
        <ul>
            <% @project.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    <% end %>

...

<% end %>
```

How to include them into main app page & show them always in top?

Answer (score 1):

> How to include them into main app page & show them always in top?

This is deeper than just adding a `partial`  (as `Umang Raghuvanshi` suggested).

The problem is that the `errors` method is part of an `@object`, which means you have to make sure you're able to access this object whenever you want to output the errors in `application.html.erb`.

Partials should *never* be dependent on `@instance_variables` - they're meant to be loaded in any part of your app. You can pass [local variables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables) to them, allowing you to send predefined data as you need.

In your case, I would use a partial **but** populate it with a content_for:

--

This is what I'd do:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= render partial: "shared/errors" %>

#app/views/shared/_errors.html.erb
<%= content_tag :div, class: "errors" do %>

    <% if errors.try?(:any?) %>

        <% errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <%= content_tag :li, msg %>
        <% end %>

    <% else %>

        <% flash = %w(notice error alert) %>
        <% flash.each do |f| %>
            <%= content_tag :div, class: f, flash => [f.to_sym] if flash[f.to_sym] %>
        <% end %>

        <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <% end %>
<% end %>

#app/views/projects/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
   <%= render "shared/errors", locals: {errors: @project.errors} %>
<% end %>
```

This will allow you to style the `.errors` div to be absolutely position at the top:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ed4pcyc6/)

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
.errors { 
   display: inline-block;
   width: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 5%;
}
```

Comment: I fix some error in your code, also I get `undefined local variable or method 'errors'`. What's wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Which parts of my code had errors? Where does that error point to in the code? Is it the partial or the main page?

Comment: Please, see the difference in your. Also I don't understand why `t` `flash => [f.to_sym] if flash[t.to_sym]` here. Maybe we need `f` like previously. It's in all my pages.

Comment: sorry, it should be `f` - I'll change.

Comment: Sorry got my conditional logic mixed up :)

Comment: Can you post line ref? I updated the partial call to check whether any `errors` exist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94603/discussion-between-kirbrown-and-rich-peck).

Answer (score 0):

Extract the code into a partial and include it into your `application.html.erb`.

*_your_partial_name.erb*

```
<% if @project.errors.any? %>
        <h2><%= pluralize(@project.errors.count, "error") %> prevented this project from saving:</h2>
        <ul>
            <% @project.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    <% end %>
```

*application.html.erb*

```
<%= render partial: 'your-partial-name' %>
<% if notice %>
 <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% elsif alert %>
 <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
<% end %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
```

You could also try using flash.

Comment: And how to deal with other form pages? For example if I have another form Articles.

Comment: Set an instance variable `@errors = @thing.errors` in the controller, where @thing might be an article or a post or whatever and swap out @project.errors with @errors in the partial, @kirbrown.

Comment: Can you update your post with more info? I try to do that, but now my other pages don't work.

Comment: It's bad practice to include `@instance` variables in a partial.